# make all images' shape the same in python

Tags: python, image, resize, shapes, opencv

I wanted to utilize some images using CNN classification.

however, the problem is the image shape is different for example

```
for i in range(1,len(x_train)):
    print(print(x_train_resize[i].shape))
```

this shows the images' shapes for all the images that i am using this gives output of

```
None
(100, 100)
None
(100, 100)
None
(100, 100, 3)
None
(100, 100, 4)
```

as shown above, is there a way to make the shapes of the images that i have all the same as
(100, 100, 1) or (100, 100, 3)

Comment: shorter `for img in x_train: print(img.shape)`

Comment: you can use `pillow` to convert images between  `RGB` (3), `RGBA` (4) and `grayscale` (1). OR you can manually try to convert it - in RGBA (4) you can remove last layer (A - transparency) to get RGB (3). In `grayscale` (1) you can duplicate layer to get 3 layers to get (almost) the same as `RGB`

Answer (score 0):

`(100, 100)` means `grayscale` image.

`(100, 100, 3)` means `RGB` image.

`(100, 100, 4)` means `RGBA` image.

---

If you have numpy `grayscale` image `img_gray` with shape `(100,100)` then you can duplicate layers to create `(100, 100, 3)` like in `RGB`

```
img_rgb = np.dstack((img_gray, img_gray, img_gray))
```

If you add `alpha` layer with values `255` then you get `(100, 100, 4)` like in `RGBA`

```
alpha = np.ones((100, 100), dtype='uint8') * 255

img_rgba = np.dstack((img_rgb, alpha))
```

---

If you have `img_rgba` with `(100, 100, 4)` then you can skip `alpha` layer to get `img_rgb`

```
img_rgb = img_rgba[:,:,:3]
```

to convert `rgb` to `grayscale` you could calculate

```
img_gray = (img_rgb[:,:,0] + img_rgb[:,:,1] + img_rgb[:,:,2]) // 3
```

but better is formula `GRAY = 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B`

```
img_gray = int(0.2126 * img_rgb[:,:,0] + 0.7152 * img_rgb[:,:,1] + 0.0722 * img_rgb[:,:,2])
```

Wikipedia: [Converting colour to greyscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale)

---

If you use `OpenCV` which also use numpy arrays then it has function to convert colors.

`gray` to `RGB`

```
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

`gray` to `RBGA`

```
img_rgba = cv2.cvtColor(img_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA)
```

`RGB` to `RBGA`

```
img_rgba = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
```

and in other direction

`RGB` to `gray`

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

`RBGA` to `gray`

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgba, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
```

`RGBA` to `RBG`

```
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgba, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
```

---

You could also use `pillow` [Image.convert](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) but it needs to

- convert `numpy array` to `pillow Image` - `img = Image.fromarray(array)`,
- convert color - `img = img.convert(...)`,
- convert back `pillow Image` to `numpy array` - `array = np.asarray(img)`.

Doc: [Image.fromarray()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray)

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example

```
import numpy as np

img_gray = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype='uint8')

# create image with cross
for y in range(100):
    img_gray[y,y] = int(255 * (y/100))
    img_gray[y,99-y] = int(255 * (y/100))
        
print('img_gray.shape:', img_gray.shape)  # (100, 100)

img_rgb = np.dstack((img_gray, img_gray, img_gray))
print('img_rgb.shape:', img_rgb.shape)  # (100, 100, 3)

alpha = np.ones((100, 100), dtype='uint8') * 255

img_rgba = np.dstack((img_rgb, alpha))
print('img_rgba.shape:', img_rgba.shape)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(img_gray)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(img_rgba)
plt.show()

# --- OpenCV ---

import cv2

img_cv2_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
print('img_cv2_rgb.shape:', img_cv2_rgb.shape)

img_cv2_rgba = cv2.cvtColor(img_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA)
print('img_cv2_rgba.shape:', img_cv2_rgba.shape)

img_cv2_rgba2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv2_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
print('img_cv2_rgba2.shape:', img_cv2_rgba2.shape)

cv2.imshow('gray', img_gray)
cv2.imshow('rgb',  img_cv2_rgb)
cv2.imshow('rgba', img_cv2_rgba)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```